Fetching Transaction Hashes
I'm encountering an issue when retrieving transaction hashes. Essentially, I want to input the token address and obtain all parsed transactions, then filter those addresses that swapped the token on Raydium. I used connection.getSignaturesForAddress(tokenAddress);, but it only returns up to 1000 transactions. Is there any other way to obtain all the addresses or any way to get all transactions?

getSignatureForAddress has a before parameter which means it starts searching from that signature. So you could create a loop that goes backwards and starts again searching from the oldest signature backwards.
Here are the docs:
https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress
